# Issue adding selected attribute to selection option box correctly

Tags: jsp, html-select

I have a select option box called 'CMDSchedStatus' that contains a list of options.  I am trying to set the 'selected' attribute depending on a session variable that I have set up previously:

```
   session.setAttribute("Status",wkStatus) ;
```

I have the following code in my JSP but I am clearly doing this wrong on the syntax error:

```
    <select size="1" id="CMDSchedStatus" name="CMDSchedStatus" class="combosmall">
       <option value=""></option>
       <option value="NP" <c:if test="${Status == "NP"}"> <c:out value= "selected=selected"/>  </c:if> >NP</option>
       <option value="RP" <c:if test="${Status == "RP"}"> <c:out value= "selected=selected"/>  </c:if> >RP</option>
       <option value="VP" <c:if test="${Status == "VP"}"> <c:out value= "selected=selected"/> </c:if> >VP</option>
       <option value="CP" <c:if test="${Status == "CP"}"> <c:out value= "selected=selected"/> </c:if> >CP</option>
    </select>
```

Can you look at this and see what is causing the syntax error and whether the processing is actually correct?  Seems like the smarter way to do this would be some kind of foreach but couldn't figure out this with fixed values

Thanks

Comment: Instead of using ${Status.equals("NP")} you should try ${Status == "NP")}  or use ${Status eq "NP"}

Comment: i did update the statement.  I am still getting an error saying 'equal symbol expected' message so I am still missing or have too much of something else.

Comment: In order to correct error, use for example <c:if test='${Status == "NP"}'>   Also, look at my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this working example.

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<c:set var="myList" value="NONE,NP,RP,VP,CP"/>
<c:set var="Status" value='${param.CMDSchedStatus}'/>   
<html>
    <body>
        <form>
            <select size="1" id="CMDSchedStatus" name="CMDSchedStatus" class="combosmall">
            <c:forEach items="${myList}" var="current">
                <option value="${current}"
                <c:if test="${current == Status}"> selected="selected"</c:if>
                >${current}</option>
            </c:forEach>
            </select> 
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That did the trick.   I had a feeling that doing a for each would be better but the hardcoded option values was confusing me.   By the way, what is the formatting of the myList to replace NONE with ' ""  '

Comment: If you want an empty option, then use <c:set var="myList" value=" ,NP,RP,VP,CP"/>